# Accessing javascript open source API

Tags: javascript, json

how can i communicate with Mega.co.nz? They claim that they are using a open source java-script project that we (developers) can use to communicate with their server. But how does someone begin? I would really appreciate if i can get some tips on this.

Comment: Have you checked out their developer's page? https://mega.co.nz/#developers

Comment: Hello Jack, i do know that they have an API. I'm just unsure where to begin. I.E How should i call the URL to sign in and retrieve data? Do you know of any tutorial that gives overview of how to retrieve data using URL API etc?

Comment: That's not how SO works; if you're stuck with a particular problem, post That as a question. This is way too generic and answers can't really be objectively measured.

Answer (score 0):

API's are mostly designed for third-party developers' use so they usually provide documentations on how to connect to it (e.g. which URL's to call, what parameters to pass and what is the expected response.) Most of the time, you can find it on their website, if not, you should ask them for it.

Comment: Hi Jhourland, they do have an api i'm just unsure where to start from. I.E what should i be doing to Login retreving content once singed in.. Their api is https://mega.co.nz/#developers

Answer (score 0):

As it states on the mega.co.nz developer page the API specification has not been documented yet. You would have to reverse engineer the HTML and javascript on the site to learn how to use it. Or wait until full documentation is available.